How can I access devices on my LAN through Wireguard VPN?
I have an OpenWRT router that serves IPs in the subnet 10.0.1.1/24. There is a Wireguard VPN running on the router that serves IPs in the subnet 10.10.0.1/24. When I connect to the VPN (but am not on the LAN), I get an IP 10.10.0.x. I can reach the router at 10.10.0.1 and at 10.0.1.1, but I cannot access a server at 10.0.1.y.
How can I access the host on the lan at 10.0.1.y when connected to the VPN? My client I'm testing on is an Android phone.
UPDATE
Thanks for the help from the comments. @JW0914's suggestion helped me fix it. I had to allow forwarding to the LAN from the Wireguard zone in OpenWRT.

What does running tcpdump/wireshark on the server reveal? Does the server at least receive packets from the phone?

Can you provide a copy of your wireguard VPN config (with the keys redacted of-course).  I wonder if you need something like AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0 in the client.   Also check that the subnet mask being assigned on your LAN is a /24 (ie its possible that DHCP is assigning out of a /24 but the netmask is a /8 - which would be a problem).

In the OpenWrt firewall, is traffic allowed between the VPN's firewall zone and whatever zone the server is in (I'm assuming lan)? input, output, and forward should all be ACCEPT (either in the LuCI Firewall webpage or /etc/config/firewall)
